# Can we get a dedicated Stack Exchange site for clouds (AWS, Google Cloud Platform, and Azure)?

Tags: discussion

Most of the questions on the **[AWS Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws)** are about cloud architecture configuration, not programming.

Meanwhile, a lot of the AWS services don't have tags on Super User and Server Fault sites.

Comment: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/1099857)

Comment: *"A lot of the AWS services don't have tags in superuser/ serverfault forums"* - they are not forums, and the fact that they do not exist does not imply that they cannot exist.

Comment: Just to note: I am not against the idea of having a stack exchange site dedicated to cloud environments as it is a pretty wild topic that has a strong "don't know and don't wanna know" component to it. It is probably a good idea to give people who do get energy from the subject to have a place to congregate. But Stack Overflow would remain the main lure for such questions I'm afraid, because people want to post questions where there are the most amount of active people under the illusion that it'll give them more chance of receiving answers faster.

Answer (score 5):

No, but we should recognize that the [AWS Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws) and these tags are encouraging non-programming posts and move them to **Server Fault**.

Comment: Or just close them, perhaps with a suggestion to ask outside of SE.  I suspect many of the off-topic posts here are also off topic at Server Fault.